# Calculating sum based on CustomerID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Okay so I'm trying to help my friend with a query.

The question asks to calculate the amount owed by each customer, and display the TotalAmount, CustomerName and CustomerID.

We tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) AS totalBalance, customerName, customerID
FROM invoices;
```

This seems simple enough, but I'm afraid this won't give each customer a unique sum, and I can't test these until tomorrow because I don't have access to a database program at the moment.

Comment: You are missing a `group by`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. I appreciate it, I only offered to help her so I could start practicing again, which is why I decided to ask here.

Comment: You should learn about SQL Fiddle so you can practice SQL queries on the web.

Comment: @gordonlinoff great point bringing up SQL Fiddle. OP, here's an example for your query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/346ba3/1), if you'd like.

Comment: Wow, that sql fiddle is pretty sweet. I had no idea it existed.  Thanks for that one! Also, now that I know I don't have a database program on my computer, I'm making it a priority to get one tomorrow since they're free for students.

Comment: @user3471404 MySQL is open source and available on Mac OSX and Windows. I assumed that's what you were using as it's what you tagged.

Comment: It's a weird situation McAdam. I don't currently have a database program on my laptop.  I just got a new HDD. Kind of forgot that when I offered to help my friend.  The college I go to offers free programs for IT students. I'm going to grab those in the morning when I'm on campus.  Thank you for the SQL Fiddle site though. I'm going to make good use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum a value, you need to make a group. Otherwise, how would MySQL know which values to sum? I assume in this case you will group by customerID, but that is just assumption.

Try this:

```
SELECT customerID, customerName, SUM(balance)
FROM invoices
GROUP BY customerID;
```

**EDIT**
The above query assumes your customerID is unique and that it would be sufficient enough to group by that. If it's not unique, it would be a good idea to group by customerID and name like so:

```
GROUP BY customerID, customerName;
```

Comment: That should be `GROUP BY customerID, customerName`

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure test it first thing in the morning, when I can use the database.

Comment: Look into SQL Fiddle - see my comment on your question.

Comment: sorry I didn't realise MySQL can allow you to include  nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause - your query was fine!

Comment: @Trent, no biggie. I think the opposite is not true though. If it is in group by, it must be in select. However, it can be in select but doesn't have to be in group by.

Comment: Also, @Trent, what I meant was, if customerID is unique, it is good enough to group by that, because it will group each customer individually.